# The specified network password is not correct

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate, pfx

I am trying to import a .pfx file using powershell. I created a self signed certificate in iis and used this code to import it however it fails and generates this error `The specified network password is not correct`.

```
$cert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath (Resolve-Path $_.File) -CertStoreLocation cert:\localMachine\my
```

Comment: Did you specify the password via the `-Password` parameter?

Comment: You forgot to specify a password to decrypt PFX.

Comment: No, I haven't add any password

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, it was simply a wrongly formed password.

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString YOURSECRETPASSHERE -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\Certificate.pfx" -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' -Password $secureString
```